# I tried to create a 3 column grid with css flexbox but not all of it is lining up. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, codepen

Here is the link to the page: https://codepen.io/emma-billerbeck/pen/JjXjwQO

I'm sure it's probably something to do with the margins or padding, but I can't seem to de-bug the issue. I want the white box/areas to line up with the rest of the pricing boxes, but it's shifting 5-6 pixels to the right instead. Here is a snippet of the code I'm struggling with:

```
<style> #pricing {margin-top: 20px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center;} .product {display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; text-align: center; width: calc(100%  / 3); margin: 10px; border: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 3px;} .product > .level {background-color: #ddd; color: black; padding: 15px 0; width: 100%; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 700;} .product > h2 {margin-top: 25px;} .product > ol {margin: 5px 0;} .product > ol > li {padding: 2px 0; color: black;} .product > button {border: 0; margin: 25px 0; background-color: #dee21e; font-weight: 400; font-family: oswald; width: 120px; height: 30px;} .product > button:hover {background-color: white; transition: background-color 1s;} @media (max-width: 800px) {#pricing {flex-direction: column;} .product {max-width: 300px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 10px;} </style>

<section id="pricing">
  <div class="product" id="avanti">
    <div class="level">Avanti West Coast</div>
    <h2>$15/month</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>Travel the west coast for cheaper.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    </ol>
    <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="product" id="crosscountry">
    <div class="level">CrossCountry</div>
    <h2>$20/month</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>Take your train trip up a notch with CrossCountry.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    </ol>
    <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="product" id="gwr">
    <div class="level">GWR</div>
    <h2>$25/month</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>Travel Europe for much cheaper with GWR.</li>
      <li>Great for the East coast.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
    </ol>
    <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `.product > ol { padding-left: 0; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are floating the li items on the `<ol>` list if you update the CSS with the below this should resolve your issue.

Removing the padding from the `<ol>` and also aligning the list items correctly.

```
.product > ol {
  padding: 0;
}

.product > ol > li {
  padding: 2px 0;
  color: black;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a set with on the `li` elements meaning the alignment won't work on certain screen sizes. Set these properties to fix the alignment.

```
.product > ol {
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 90%;
}

li {
    width: 100%;
}
```